# Conditioning error, progression of logic in mutate/elseif_ pipeline

Tags: r

I'm trying to work out why a code like this won't give me the expected results. I understand there are better ways of achieving the results (cut, etc.) but I am specifically trying to understand why the **mutate>ifelse pipeline progression to replace values** doesn't work.

```
A <- c(1,0,0,0,NA,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,NA)
B <- c(1,0,0,NA,0,1,1,1,0,1,NA,1,0,1,NA,NA,1,0,01,0,0,0,NA,0,1,0,1)
C <- c(0,NA,0,1,0,1,NA,1,0,1,NA,0,1,0,NA,NA,1,0,01,NA,0,0,NA,1,NA,NA,1)
df <- data.frame(A, B, C)

df$D <- NA
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(D=ifelse(A==0 & B==0 & C==0,0,D)) %>%  #assign 0 to d IF all 3 variables 0
  mutate(D=ifelse(A==0 | B==0 | C==0,0,D)) %>%  #now assign 0 to d IF ANY of 3 variables 0
  mutate(D=ifelse(A==1 | B==1 | C==1,1,D))      #now reassign d to 1 if any of the variables has the value 1

> summary(as.factor(df$D))
   0    1 NA's 
   2   19    6
```

But looking at cross tabulation, my aims is to get 0=2 and NA=2 and rest assigned 1. I can't figure out why my code's logic is not working.

```
> ftable(xtabs(~A+B+C, df, addNA = TRUE, na.action = NULL)) #matches AV variable
      C 0 1 NA
A  B          
0  0    2 0  2
   1    0 4  1
   NA   0 1  1
1  0    3 2  1
   1    3 0  1
   NA   0 0  1
NA 0    1 0  0
   1    0 2  0
   NA   0 0  2
```

Edit: corrected typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code step by step, specificslly the two mutate commands with the OR conditions. For rows that contain missing and 1s (but no zeroes), R can‘t check if this row contains a zero, because it does not know what NA might be. So the second mutate returns NA for any row that has only 1s and NAs. The third step dows the same, just with 1s. Any row that only contains 0s and NAs will then return NA.

You can verify this by:

```
x <- c(0, 0, NA)
any(x == 0)

[1] TRUE

any(x == 1)

[1] NA
```

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(D = case_when(A == 0 & B == 0 & C == 0 ~ 0,
                       is.na(A) & is.na(B) & is.na(C) ~ NA_real_,
                       TRUE ~ 1))
```

which gives:

```
    A  B  C  D
1   1  1  0  1
2   0  0 NA  1
3   0  0  0  0
4   0 NA  1  1
5  NA  0  0  1
6   0  1  1  1
7   1  1 NA  1
8   0  1  1  1
9   1  0  0  1
10  0  1  1  1
11  0 NA NA  1
12  1  1  0  1
13  1  0  1  1
14  1  1  0  1
15 NA NA NA NA
16 NA NA NA NA
17 NA  1  1  1
18  1  0  0  1
19  0  1  1  1
20  0  0 NA  1
21  0  0  0  0
22  1  0  0  1
23  1 NA NA  1
24  1  0  1  1
25  0  1 NA  1
26  1  0 NA  1
27 NA  1  1  1
```

And then

```
df2 %>% count(D)

   D  n
1  0  2
2  1 23
3 NA  2
```

Comment: Thank you! As I mention in the question, I realize there is other ways to manipulate the data. I'm specifically concerned with THIS method and why it doesn't work since based on everything I've read it should.

Comment: Sure, I just completed/updated my post with an explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had assumed it would prioritize the 0 (if one 0 is present, it doesn't matter what the other values are NA or otherwise, it would assign 0). By why doesn't it do this when the row is (NA, 1,1)=assigns 1 but not (0,0,NA)=assigns NA? It's the same code?

Comment: Forget what I wrote before. See my update at the beginning of my post.

Comment: Thanks for following up: "So the second mutate returns NA for any row that has only 1s and NAs." This isn't true, checking the data frame, the rows that are 1s and NAs all return 1. Now, I completely take out the second OR mutate statement, the zero+NA rows start returning 0 too. There seems to be some weird phenomenon happening where the two mutates don't work together?

Comment: Nope. Please check again. So if you run the first and second mutate (but not the third) you‘ll see that and row with only 1s and NAs returns NA. I.e rows 7, 17, 23, 27.

Comment: If I run line #2 alone mutate(D=ifelse(A==0 | B==0 | C==0,0,D)) all rows with any 0s are assigned 0 (regardless if if there is an NA or not); the rows 7,17,23, 27 are all NA because they are 1s and not 0s. If I run line #3 mutate(D=ifelse(A==1 | B==1 | C==1,1,D)) alone any rows with the value 1 are assigned 1 (regardless of there is an NA or not). When the two lines are run together the issue of 0s not being assigned 0 occurs.

Comment: Let‘s look at row 2. running mutate # 1 does not change it, because not all values are 0. the second mutate will turn it into 0 because at least one value is 0. the third mutate then tuens it into NA because you are checking if at least 1 occurs. But R can‘t do the test because you only have 0s and NA. And R does not know if the NA represents a 1 or a 0 or sth. else. That‘s why it turns row 2 into NA after the third mutate.

Comment: Thanks, I see what I was thinking wrong. I also just realized that there is an error in my question (0,0,NA should be assigned as 0 not 1, for example in line 5), which led to an error in your solution for anyone who is reading this in the future. I'll edit it. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If the solution/explanation solves your problem, please consider flagging it as your accepted answer so that others can see and benefit from it.